# xlsx package under Ubuntu cannot set values

Tags: r, ubuntu-12.04, xlsx, rjava

I am running the following script

```
library(xlsx);
wb <- loadWorkbook("/home/.../MyFile.xlsx") #works fine
sh <- getSheets(wb) #works fine
rw <- getRows(sh[[1]]) #-works fine
rc <- getCells(rw) # works fine
v <- lapply(rc, getCellValue) # works fine
v['21.4'] #works fine, returns the correct value
setCellValue(rc['21.4'], 'Hallo') #fails

Error in .jcall(cell, "V", "setCellValue", value) : 
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

after repeating the command

```
Error in .jcall(cell, "V", "setCellValue", value) : 
  RcallMethod: cannot determine object class
```

It happens in RStudio and in the classical R terminal under Ubuntu 12.04 32Bit.
Please help!

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem in Windows 7 x64 and I think that there is a mistake in 'xlsx' documentation. However instead of

```
setCellValue(rc['21.4'], 'Hallo')
```

try

```
setCellValue(rc[['21.4']], 'Hallo')
```

Worked for me.
Kuba

Comment: And it still works. It has something to do with the list type.